# Python: Modify already defined list in the both senses, modify the entry values, modify the number of values

Tags: python, list, arraylist

This is a python code I was designed to get input values from users. Here I already have defined a list of integers, but I want to modify these values as well as increase the number of values in this. For example, the list "scores" given here contains 6 values, I want to build a program that should contain more than 6 values in the list and modify the first 6 values according to user input.

I tried the following:

```
    scores = [43, 12, 6, 78, 2, 14]
    #updating this list and increasing the number of values it is carrying by user input
    n = int(input("How many values you want to include in a list: "))
    for i in range(n):
        print("for ", i, "student:")
        score = int(input("Enter the score :"))
        #scores.append(score)
        if i in range(n):    
            scores[i] = score
        else:
            scores.append(score)


    print(scores)
```

and I am expecting to modify the list "scores", which should contain more than 6 values and the first 6 values of that list should be according to the values inserted by the user.

Someone, please guide me if this is possible to modify a list of integers with simultaneously increasing the number of values in it. Thank you!

Comment: I finally got it, replacing ```if i in range(n):``` by ```if i in range(len(scores)): ```does the job

Comment: if that works for you, please answer and/or close this question